# Do I need new documents after refusal to apply again for UK?

Tags: uk, transit, visa-refusals

I was refused a transit visa to UK because I didn't present the bank statement that has proof of my salary payments. I am a Ghanaian, living in Ghana, and I want to reapply.

Can I send back my old documents and add my bank statement that has proof of my salary or do I need to present new documents?

Comment: *"...add my bank statement that has proof of my salary..."*  Of course you can, but read http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105 under the section 'Opacity'.